# Overriding operator = so that we may copy class instance using = without shallow copy issue

Tags: c++, class, oop

Suppose we defined Book class and we want to use = to copy Book class instance without shallow copy issue which will arise in the below code:

```
Book b;
Book a = b;
```

So we write code like this:

```
Book & Book::operator=(const Book & rhs)
{
  if(this != &rhs)
  {
  //details
  }
  return *this;
}
```

But why do we have to return Book &, instead of Book or even Book*?

Also, can we use if(*this != rhs) instead of if(this != &rhs)? If not, why can this not be used?

Comment: There is nothing in your question that specific to a "shallow copy" problem. You're also not using the assignment operator in your code sample.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
Book b = a;
```

Is a copy construction and does *not* call the assignment operator. Instead it invokes:

```
Book::Book(Book const&);
```

The assignment operator returns a `Book&` so you can do this:

```
a = b = c; // all three are Book objects
```

---

With respect to your second question, no, you cannot say `*this == rhs` as this would invoke `operator==(Book const&, Book const&)`. You want to compare addresses, so `if (this != &rhs)`.

Comment: Edited my question. I am thinking about overriding = to avoid shallow copy issues, while still retaining =.

Comment: @uzawalaoma: See edit. Does that answer your question?

Comment: `a = b = c` would work also if the operator returned `Book` and not `Book&`, so that's not the reason.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the other answer, your code does not call `operator=`. However, the question is still valid if your example code was changed to

```
Book a, b;
// ...
a = b;
```

To answer the first part of the question, you need to return a reference, because this kind of code must work correctly:

```
Foo x;
Foo y;
(x=y).bar = 42;
```

The above must change the value of `x.bar` to 42.

To answer the second part, the point of comparing `this == &rhs` is to avoid copying in the case of code like

```
x = x;
```

If you are only doing a shallow copy, you could also compare `*this == rhs`, but that might lead to wrong results in case of deep compare and deep copy.